# Counting total photo comments of a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, count, comments, photos

I'm trying to count the total comments to all photos of a user. My query below works but it fails on some users with lots of photos and comments.

Any idea why it fails on some users? Can the query below be improved?

```
SELECT '' FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT aid, object_id FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = $uid )) LIMIT 5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to SELECT?
You can not do `"*"` selects on FQL tables to select all fields - you have to specify exactly which fields you want.

Comment: I'm just trying to count the results so I'm selecting no fields.

Comment: FQL is not identical to SQL there are some differences. You can read from [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) in the first few paragraphs all the limitations/differences should be be stated.

Comment: The query does work most of the time. It's just for users with a lot of photos it fails.

Comment: you could try requesting fewer photos but performing 2 or more requests.

Comment: Your suggestion made me realize I was only limiting the total result. When I limit the photo result to 2000 it works. Thanks a lot that solved my issue.

The query below works on users with a lot of photos.
    
`SELECT '' FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT aid, object_id FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner= $uid) LIMIT 2000) LIMIT 5000`